# What are the minimum requirements for a custom module to be listed in admin/modules?

Tags: 8

Following the instructions in [the documentation for creating a custom module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/let-drupal-8-know-about-your-module-with-an-infoyml-file), I created a directory `modules/custom/my_module` and put a `my_module.info.yml` with some minimal contents like this:

```
name: 'My Module'
description: 'Does some stuff'
package: 'Custom'

type: module
core: 8.x
```

In that documentation page, directly after the section that describes the `info.yml` file, there's a section called "Debugging .info.yml files" and the first item there is "Module is not listed on admin/modules". I'm *assuming* that means that after I created the `info.yml` file in the right place, the module should be listed on admin/modules.

Is that assumption correct, or do I need to get farther along in the process before the module is listed on admin/modules? Is there something I need to run to refresh the list or should Drupal be able to find the module automatically as soon as the `info.yml` file exists, even though there's nothing else in it yet?

Comment: Did you try uninstalling or installing a module to see if the list of modules does then include yours?

Comment: That should be enough - you used to need a .module file but not any more. You could try rebuilding the cache, although if memory serves I think just visiting the modules page should refresh the list (in theory)

Comment: Sorry, I had to step away from my desk unexpectedly right after asking the question. I haven't tried either of those things, but I will when I return. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: To make it clearer: The Drupal 8 documentation says that a .info.yaml file is sufficient for Drupal to recognize a module, and that has not changed. If the list of modules doesn't show the new module, Drupal is showing the list it has in its cache.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thanks for the clarification. I actually just figured out why the new module wasn't showing up. My app is running in a container and it turns out that my working directory is not synced to the container like I thought it was.

Comment: @kiamlaluno It seems the problem that prompted me to ask this question won't be easily reproducible for others, and I'm not sure if the question is really worth asking otherwise. Should I just delete it?

Comment: There is not need to delete it, so far. We can just close it, since there is a closing reason that applies.